# Delete Temp Files in Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix, del

I'd like to remove temp build files during or after my laravel-mix build.
Here's some code that I have currently, but `del` isn't working:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const del = require('del');

// compile sass into temp css file
mix.sass('resources/stylesheets/style.scss', 'public/css/temp.css');

// compile css
mix.styles([
    // other css stylesheets here...
    'public/css/temp.css' // include temp css file
], 'public/css/admin.min.css');

// delete temp css file
del('public/css/temp.css'); // not deleting the file
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not directly creating the admin.min.css?

Comment: @KuebelElch15 you can't mix css and sass files inside `mix.sass()` so this is my workaround.

Comment: Oh, I've overread the `//other css stylesheets` comment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to solve this by running `del` within a `then()` returned by `mix.styles()`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const del = require('del');

// compile sass into temp css file
mix.sass('resources/stylesheets/style.scss', 'public/css/temp.css');

// compile css
mix.styles([
    // other css stylesheets here...
    'public/css/temp.css' // include temp css file
], 'public/css/admin.min.css').then(() => {
    del('public/css/temp.css'); // deletes the temp file
});
```

The same thing also works with `mix.scripts()`:

```
mix.scripts([
    'public/js/app.js',
    'public/js/global.js',
], 'public/js/app.combined.js').then(() => {
    del('public/js/app.js');
    del('public/js/global.js');
});
```

Comment: I had no idea that those methods returned promises. I've since started importing css files in my sass files so I haven't been needing a temp file. Thanks a lot!